# How to check if a double value contains special characters

Tags: java, double

I was writing a code for a program in which the user enters 2 to 4 numbers which can be up to 2 decimal places long. However before the user enters these numbers they must enter the pound symbol, e.g. #12.34. I was wondering how i would check if the double value entered began with the pound sign, and if the user forgot to input it, to re-prompt them to do it again. So far im using a String value and the '.startsWith()' code, but I'm finding later on that a String value is making the rest of the program impossible to code, so i was wanting to keep it a double value. This is the code I have at the moment but wish to change to a double:

```
String input;
System.out.print("Enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
input = keyboard.next();
while (!input.startsWith("#")) {
 System.out.print("Re-enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
 input = keyboard.next();
}
```

I was wanting to replace the String with double as mentioned previously.

Comment: Probably you should not prompt user to enter pound sign, instead restrict it. Use pound sign only for display purpose.

Comment: Double.parseDouble might help

Comment: Check if the string starts with pound, then parse the remaining of the string to a double.

Comment: Not an answer, but: In case the user did not enter a `#`, do not ask to repeat the input; just append the `#` at the beginning of the string. But if you want to calculate with it, why do you need that `#` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input;
System.out.print("Enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
input = keyboard.next();
while (!input.startsWith("#")) {
 System.out.print("Re-enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
 input = keyboard.next();
}
// if your excution reaches here. then it means the values entered by user is starting from '#'.
String temp = input;
double value = Double.parseDouble(temp.replace("#",""));
```

For the rest of the program use `value`. I think the coding should be possible now.

Answer (score 3):

A `double` value doesn't have a currency symbol. You should check for the currency symbol as you are doing and remove it before parsing the double.

```
String input;
System.out.print("Enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
input = keyboard.next();
while (!input.startsWith("£")) {
   System.out.print("Re-enter the 4 numbers with a pound key: ");
   input = keyboard.next();
}
doulble number = Double.parseDouble(input.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You *should* use the `startsWith` method. I don't know why you say that

> I'm finding later on that a String value is making the rest of the program impossible to code

Basically, you want to prompt it repeatedly until the user enters the # sign. So why not use a while loop?

```
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
String s = keyboard.next();
double d = 0.0; // You actually wnat to store the user input in a
                // variable, right?
while (!s.trim().startWith("#")) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter the number in the correct format. Try again.");
    s = keyboard.next();
    try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         continue;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

That's a lot of code!

Explanation:

First, it prompts the user to enter a number and store the input in `s`. That's easy to understand. Now here comes the hard part. We want to loop until the user enters the input with the correct format. Let's see what kind of invalid inputs are there:

- The user does not enter a # sign
- The user does not enter a number

The first one is handled by the `startsWith` method. If the input does not start with #, ask the user again. Before that, `trim` is first called to trim off whitespace in the input so that input like `"    #5.90"` are valid. The second is handled by this part:

```
    try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         continue;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        continue;
    }
```

If the input is in a wrong format, ask the user again. If the user enters a string with a length less than 1, ask the user again.

"But wait! Why is there a call to the `substring` method?" you asked. If the user *does* enter a # in the front, followed by a correct number format, how would you convert that string to a double? Here I just kind of trim the first character off by calling substring.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this which removes all character that's not a number or a point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input;
    System.out.println("Input a number: ");
    while (!(input = br.readLine()).equals("quit")) {
        Double parsedDouble;
        if (input.matches("#[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{1,2}")) {
            parsedDouble = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll("[^0-9.]+", ""));
            System.out.println("double: " + parsedDouble);
            System.out.println("Input another number: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid. Try again. Example: #10.10");
        }
    }
}
```